# How to move files between 2 servers, dedicated server and azure VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, azure, dedicated-server, file-transfer

I am moving from a dedicated server on a hosting company to a new windows azure VM, I need to transfer all files from dedicated server to the new VM, there are about 200GB files to move, I want to know the best approach to move files to the new server, both servers are windows OS but sure not on the same network, I tried ftp transfer but it is very slow.

Comment: About the best answer we can give you is "Copy the files using a method appropriate to the amount of data, type of data, and other local considerations." I'm not sure what you're expecting us to tell you here given the lack of detail in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have virtually innumerable options for copying files between servers.

FTP, SMB (drag and drop, or a command line copy like robocopy), BITS, HTTP, even SCP.  Which one is "best" depends entirely on your preferences and specific situation (which you haven't told us enough about to make a determination on).

As to speed, you're transferring 200GB over the internet.  Yes, it's going to be slow.